# how to backup a cloud site on rackspace cloud with code and database

Tags: backup, backup-restoration, rackspace

i have my website hosted on rackspace cloud server . i need to make backup of code + database of my cloud site. 
Please give me link of any documentation which suggests steps to perform this or link to alternative method so i can achieve this

Comment: What DBMS are you using? In most cases there is some kind of "replication" functionality built in. As for back-ups of code, start with [rsync](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rsync). It is very easy to have incremental back-ups to a remote NFS volume.

Comment: Where do you want your code backed up to? Where is your code located on the server?

Comment: i am using php+mysql in website. and i want to backup code+files+db on server only(download also if possible in zip) so that i can restore it later if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options here:

1. Leverage the Rackspace Cloud Backup solution
2. Write a multi part custom backup script (mysqldump to disk, zip up files plus backup files, rsync/ftp/sftp the file to another location).

For the Rackspace Cloud Backup option, I'd suggest checking out the following documentation:

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/rackspace-cloud-backup-overview

There are links for installing the agent, which will then allow you to specify a backup configuration within your MyCloud portal.

Option 2 is a bit more involved and will require custom shell scripting. One starting point may be:

http://www.noupe.com/how-tos/10-ways-to-automatically-manually-backup-mysql-database.html

Answer (score 0):

Rackspace Managed SysOps uses our [Cloud Backup](https://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/product-page/cloud-backup) tool for web content and [Holland](http://hollandbackup.org/) for MySQL backups. Make sure to include the files which Holland creates in your Cloud Backup config.

Cloud Backup does not create a "zip" which you could download locally, but it does let you restore to any of your Cloud Servers (after which you could make a zip if you like).